# Any way in THREE.js to get the Cylinder's top center after rotation?

Tags: 3d, rotation, three.js

I am new to WebGL and Three.js. And I made the original point of a cylinder to the bottom center.

Code:

```
var cylinderGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( topRadius, botRadius, randomCyliderHeight);
cylinderGeometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( 0, randomCyliderHeight/2, 0 ) );
var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( cylinderGeometry, material );
```

Then I rotate the cylinder like:

```
cylinder.rotation.x = θ1;
cylinder.rotation.y = θ2;
cylinder.rotation.z = θ3;
```

If the cylinder original point's coordinate is (x,y,z).

Is there any way in THREE.js to get the cylinder's top center after rotation?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you translate your cylinder geometry, the top center is:

```
var point = new THREE.Vector3( 0, randomCyliderHeight, 0 );
```

Now apply the same rotation to the point that you applied to the cylinder:

```
point.applyEuler( cylinder.rotation );
```

three.js r.68